# Step by Step Guide to install Syntaxnet on Window 7 64 bit

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet

Can any body explain the step by step guide to install the Google syntaxtnet framework and the relative dependencies on windows 7 on 64 bit ?

Regards
samir

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use SyntaxNet in Windows is probably using Docker.

1. Install [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)
2. Pull the SyntaxNet container:

docker pull tensorflow/syntaxnet

3. Run the container:

   docker run --rm -ti -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/syntaxnet

It will immediately fire up a Jupyter Notebook. Copy the link and paste it in the browser.

4. Open a Jupyter Notebook and navigate to this directory:

   cd ../../syntaxnet/
5. Now run demo.sh

   'Bob bought a pizza.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh